# Fill canvas outside rectangle

Tags: android, canvas

I want to fill the area outside a rectangle on a canvas. I use

```
 canvas.drawRect(pTopLeft.x, pTopLeft.y, pBotRight.x, pBotRight.y, paint);
```

to draw the rectangle, but can't figure out how to fill outside the rectangle/clip.

Thanks
Geoff

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You aren't going to fill outside the clip; that's the kind of thing clip is there to prevent! If you want to fill the space outside a rect and inside the drawing layer bounds, construct four auxiliary rects:

```
Rect above = new Rect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), pTopLeft.y);
Rect left = new Rect(0, pTopLeft.y, pTopLeft.x, pBotRight.y);
Rect right = new Rect(pBotRight.x, pTopLeft.y, canvas.getWidth(), pBotRight.y);
Rect bottom = new Rect(0, pBotRight.y, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
```

Then fill these.

Comment: Thanks Ted. I played around with filling the whole canvas then trying to make the clip region transparent - no good. Your method did the trick.

Comment: I know you have it working now, but one other possibility occurred to me: set a clip region that excludes the middle and fill. I think that if you use `canvas.clipRect(innerRect, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE)` it will punch the hole you want.

Comment: @TedHopp Actually i cant get any rectangles. Can u share me how to draw rectangle and fill rectangle outside bounds?

Comment: @ImMathan - Please post a separate question explaining what you are trying to do, what you have tried, and what about it isn't working. Without knowing that, it's hard to know how to help.

Comment: @TedHopp here is my question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25679259/draw-rectagle-with-fill-outside-bounds

Answer (score 19):

Thanks ted and trojanfoe - the neatest solution I've come up with is

```
    Point pTopLeft = new Point();
    Point pBotRight = new Point();

    //TODO:set x,y for points

    Rect rHole = new Rect(pTopLeft.x, pTopLeft.y, pBotRight.x, pBotRight.y);
    //assume current clip is full canvas
    //put a hole in the current clip
    canvas.clipRect(rHole,  Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);
    //fill with semi-transparent red
    canvas.drawARGB(50, 255, 0, 0);
    //restore full canvas clip for any subsequent operations
    canvas.clipRect(new Rect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight())
                    , Region.Op.REPLACE);
```

Comment: can u share me what points to be given to draw a rectangle center and fill outside the bounds?

Answer (score 2):

ICS and above ...

```
canvas.clipRect(rHole,  Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);
```

> XOR, Difference and ReverseDifference clip modes are 
>   ignored by ICS if hardware acceleration is enabled.
>
> Just disable 2D hardware acceleration in your view:
>
> myView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

Reference [Android: Howto use clipRect in API15](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9213065/2641380)

Answer (score 0):

You can't draw outside of the `Canvas`; that area belongs to the parent `View`.  Do you have the ability to subclass the parent `View` and do your drawing in that class instead?

If you want to draw outside of the `Canvas` clip then you'll have to `invalidate()` the areas you are interested in.