# Android: Howto use clipRect in API15

Tags: android, canvas

i have a problem with a custom view with running on api 15 (Android 4.0.3)

the code:

```
canvas.clipRect(10,10,100,100, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);
canvas.drawPaint(myPaint);
```

fills the full area of the view and not just the DIFFERENCE...
it works with api 8 and 9...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 15, accepted):

XOR, Difference and ReverseDifference clip modes are ignored by ICS if hardware acceleration is enabled.

Just disable 2D hardware acceleration in your view:

```
myView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```