# Draw Rectagle with fill outside bounds

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas

I am drawing an Rectangle with outside of rectangle fill. I tried some of this. But cant get the perfect one what i expected.

This is what i expected.

[image: Viewfinder]

I tried

```
    Point pTopLeft = new Point();
    Point pBotRight = new Point();
    pTopLeft.x = 100;
    pTopLeft.y = 100;
    pBotRight.x = canvas.getWidth() - 100;
    pBotRight.y = canvas.getHeight() - 100;
    Rect above = new Rect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), pTopLeft.y);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#77000000"));
    canvas.drawRect(above, paint);
    Rect left = new Rect(0, pTopLeft.y, pTopLeft.x, pBotRight.y);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#77000000"));

    canvas.drawRect(left, paint);
    Rect right = new Rect(pBotRight.x, pTopLeft.y, canvas.getWidth(),
            pBotRight.y);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#77000000"));
    canvas.drawRect(right, paint);
    Rect bottom = new Rect(0, pBotRight.y, canvas.getWidth(),
            canvas.getHeight());

    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#77000000"));
    Paint paint_text = new Paint();
    paint_text.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint_text.setTextSize(50);
    paint_text.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);

    canvas.drawText("Position Card in this Frame", canvas.getWidth() / 2,
            canvas.getHeight() - 30, paint_text);
    canvas.drawRect(bottom, paint);
```

And got like this

[image]

But i want to draw the rectangle and fill outside the bounds to achieve the rounded border. How can i do it?

**EDIT**
When i tries to draw the rectangle one over one. The layout is like this..

[image]

That i cant give `Color.TRANSPARENT` for the center rectangle which fully tranparents the second rectangle..

Comment: To draw rounded corners, use `drawRoundRect` instead of `drawRect`. It looks like you can make do with a single (rounded) rectangle without needing a hole in the middle (like you seem to be trying to do).

Comment: Ok.. Then how to fill the outside transparent shades?

Comment: I don't understand. What does "outside transparent shades" mean? Your expected graphic looks like a simple rounded rectangle (drawn twice, once with a fill and once with a white outline stroke) with a credit card image drawn on top of it. Any parts that you don't draw will appear in the background color of the view, which you can set to transparent.

Comment: Actually shades are applied to the outer rectangle only. I applied the shade to outer rectangle. But when i try to draw the inner rectangle the background shade of the outer rectangle shows. What color i need to give in the background of center rectangle?

Comment: I edited my question with your way of implementation. Please look at it..

Comment: Instead of trying to draw the inner rectangle as transparent, why not simply draw it in the background color?

Comment: I dont know how to do it... Can u share me how to do it..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm still not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish. The shape you show can be drawn as follows:

```
// set up some constants
int w = canvas.getWidth();
int h = canvas.getHeight();
RectF rect = new RectF(100, 100, w - 100, h - 100);
float radius = 10.0f; // should be retrieved from resources and defined as dp
float borderWidth = 2.0f; // ditto
int innerRectFillColor = 0x33000000; // or whatever shade it should be

// first fill the interior
Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
paint.setColor(innerRectFillColor);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, paint);
// then draw the border
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
paint.setStrokeWidth(borderWidth);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, paint);
```

If instead you want to draw around a hole (so the background shows through), the trick of drawing the surrounding rectangles won't work because of the rounded corners (the border also makes it more complicated). Instead, you can create a separate `Bitmap` that has a transparent hole and then draw that. You'll need to use a Porter-Duff transfer mode of `CLEAR` to punch the hole in the bitmap:

```
// same constants as above except innerRectFillColor is not used. Instead:
int outerFillColor = 0x77000000;

// first create an off-screen bitmap and its canvas
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas auxCanvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

// then fill the bitmap with the desired outside color
Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
paint.setColor(outerFillColor);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
auxCanvas.drawPaint(paint);

// then punch a transparent hole in the shape of the rect
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
auxCanvas.drawRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, paint);

// then draw the white rect border (being sure to get rid of the xfer mode!)
paint.setXfermode(null);
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
auxCanvas.drawRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, paint);

// finally, draw the whole thing to the original canvas
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
```

Comment: This is it.. This is what i really want. Thankq :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I punched out a rounded rectangle window from my background. You're actually drawing four rectangles around a center window, then filling that window with a RoundRectShape that has an outer radius of 0 and thin inset with rounded edges.

```
    Rect frame = new Rect(left, top, right, bottom); // Window location on screen
    int width = canvas.getWidth();
    int height = canvas.getHeight();


    paint.setColor(maskColor); // Make sure your mask is semi-transparent

    // Draw four bounding rectangles  
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, frame.top, paint); 
    canvas.drawRect(0, frame.top, frame.left, frame.bottom + 1, paint);  
    canvas.drawRect(frame.right + 1, frame.top, width, frame.bottom + 1, paint);
    canvas.drawRect(0, frame.bottom + 1, width, height, paint);

    // Create rounded rectangle to fill window 
    float outerRadii[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}; // The outside edge is just a rectangle
    float innerRadii[] = {8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8}; // The inside edge is rounded
    RoundRectShape roundRect = new RoundRectShape(outerRadii, new RectF(5,5,5,5), innerRadii); // We'll stick this shape into the frame we made

    roundRect.resize(frame.width()+1, frame.height()+1); // Adjust size to match the punched-out frame 
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(frame.left, frame.top); // The RoundRectShape draws to the canvas at (0,0), so we need to offset the canvas, draw, then restore
    roundRect.draw(canvas, paint);
    canvas.restore();
```

And here's the result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qdTw.png

Answer (score 2):

**You can get next result:**

[image: You can get next result]

**I create Custome background view**

```
class CameraShapeView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null
) : View(context, attrs) {

    private val outBackground: Paint = Paint().apply {
        color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.feature_identification_camera_document_background_color)
        style = Paint.Style.FILL
    }
    private val frameStroke: Paint = Paint().apply {
        color = Color.WHITE
        strokeWidth = 1f.toPx
        style = Paint.Style.STROKE
    }
    private val outPath = Path()
    private val framePath = Path()
    private val frameRect = RectF()

    @SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)

        outPath.reset()
        framePath.reset()

        val height = height.toFloat()
        val width = width.toFloat()

        outPath.apply {
            moveTo(0f, 0f)
            lineTo(0f, height)
            lineTo(width, height)
            lineTo(width, 0f)
            fillType = Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD
        }

        frameRect.apply {
            left = 30f.toPx
            top = (height / 2) - 300f
            right = width - 30f.toPx
            bottom = (height / 2) + 300f
        }

        framePath.addRoundRect(
            frameRect,
            16f.toPx,
            16f.toPx,
            Path.Direction.CW
        )
        outPath.addPath(framePath)
        canvas.drawPath(outPath, outBackground)
        canvas.drawPath(framePath, frameStroke)
    }
}
```

my layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?colorPrimary"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
        android:id="@+id/preview_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:captureMode="image"
        app:flash="off"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:lensFacing="back"
        app:pinchToZoomEnabled="true"
        app:scaleType="fillCenter" />

    <CameraShapeView
        android:id="@+id/camera_shape_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/capture_btn"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:src="@drawable/feature_identification_camera_shape_take_filled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Capture button image**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="72dp"
    android:height="72dp"
    android:viewportWidth="71"
    android:viewportHeight="71">

    <path
        android:pathData="M 35.5 1 C 54.5538238692 1 70 16.4461761308 70 35.5 C 70 54.5538238692 54.5538238692 70 35.5 70 C 16.4461761308 70 1 54.5538238692 1 35.5 C 1 16.4461761308 16.4461761308 1 35.5 1 Z"
        android:strokeWidth="2"
        android:strokeColor="#ffffff" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#ffffff"
        android:pathData="M 35.4994 5.9165 C 51.8378054397 5.9165 65.0827 19.1613945603 65.0827 35.4998 C 65.0827 51.8382054397 51.8378054397 65.0831 35.4994 65.0831 C 19.1609945603 65.0831 5.9161 51.8382054397 5.9161 35.4998 C 5.9161 19.1613945603 19.1609945603 5.9165 35.4994 5.9165 Z" />

</vector>
```

**Full screen shot**

[image: result of my code]

Comment: ImMathan you can try if you want